# Python pandas - Numeric column in dataframe is in exponent number

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've recently started facing this problem where in a column few values are in Exponential form and rest are regular numbers.

I want to merge two columns but it is not yielding any result for the one in exponent form. I would like to how can I overcome this problem to merge 2 dataframes.

example

```
df1
2780989
2780749
2816256

df2
2780989
2780749
2.81625e+06

pd.merge(df1,df2, on = 'column1')
2780989
2780749
```

I tried changing both columns in strings then it is either showing

```
2780989.0
2780749.0
2816256.0
```

I have a workaround which is keeping the column I want to merge as the very first column in my df but if it is on 2nd position it will start showing values as I mentioned above.

Comment: The way this numbers are printed to your console has nothing to do with their internal represention as IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: Notice that `2.81625e+06` is not equal to `2816256`. What was your expected output?

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes, these are not equal but even the values are equal in my df it is not merging with the other df

Comment: Hi MaxNoe, thanks for your comment. I didn't know that because when I tried to plot the same using matplotlib it was plotted as an exponent in the chart as well.

Comment: @Michael Th expected output is, if 2.81625e+06 and 2816256 were equal. It should get merged but it is not getting merged.

Answer (score 0):

Let's convert both dataframes to float:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[2780989,2780749,2816250]}, dtype='int')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['2780989','2780749','2.81625e+06']})

pd.merge(df1.astype(float),df2.astype(float), on='Col1')
```

Output:

```
        Col1
0  2780989.0
1  2780749.0
2  2816250.0
```