# How to read a csv in scientic notation with capital E in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I do have a csv file seperated by whitespace which looks like:

```
5.64E-4   0.1259   3.556E-4   300
2.98E-4   4.7E-3   5.322E-4   270
```

I pandas like this

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv(filepath[0], header=None, delim_whitespace=True, lineterminator='\r')
```

But I realized that pandas saves the DataFrame as a String, as it doesn't know what E means.
Can I somehow import the csv file and convert it to numeric writing, so I can plot it?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923864/python-pandas-numeric-column-in-dataframe-is-in-exponent-number

Comment: no, I already saw this. pandas recognises scientific notation with lower case e. With capital E I cannot convert it to float.

Comment: For me your solution working nice in pandas `0.23.0` with your sample data.

Comment: Maybe my problem is somewhere else, but I get the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion problem should be some not numeric values.

Possible solution is use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for parse non numeric to `NaN`s with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), because it working only for one column (`Series`):

```
print (df)
         0       1         2    3
0  5.64E-4  0.1259  3.556E-4  300
1  2.98E-4  4.7E-3       AAA  270

df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df)
          0       1         2    3
0  0.000564  0.1259  0.000356  300
1  0.000298  0.0047       NaN  270
```

Answer (score 1):

since for me the other approaches did not work, without parsing everything as NaN, I post another way of reading this variant of scientific notation.

```
# all lines will be interpreted as strings for the asked notation
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
# replace the notation across the whole dataframe
data = data.replace('E', 'e', regex=True).replace(',', '.', regex=True)
# convert notation to the one pandas allows
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```

this may not be a fine pythonic way, but it does the job for me

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to force inference of those values as floats on read:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

pandas.read_csv(filepath[0], header=None,
                delim_whitespace=True, lineterminator='\r',
                dtype=np.float64)
```

This works with upper case 'E'.

**Example**

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['5.64E-4', '0.1259', '3.556E-4'],
              'b':['a', 'b', 'c']}, dtype=np.float64)
```

**Output**

```
          a  b
0  0.000564  a
1  0.125900  b
2  0.000356  c
```

Comment: maybe I understood the problem wrong and I don't get a String DataFrame. I get the following error:

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1156, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I'd recommend `pip install --upgrade pandas` to upgrade to the latest.`0.23.0`

Comment: I have pandas 0.23.0.
I am right now scanning my file for other possible errors. By scanning through these like 30.000lines I saw like 3 cases:
Some entries were normal float values, like 3.1542
some were integer 0
and some in scientific writing like 2.34E-4 (some very small up to E-17)
Could there be an issue?